# What if I use 1 million IPv6 addresses per second then how long would it take to exhaust all the addresses?

Tags: networking, ipv6

if I use 1 million IPv6 addresses per second then how long would it take to exhaust all the addresses. Explain

Comment: This question is not about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

For a single IPv6 `/64` network it would take over `584,542` years. For all the possible IPv6 networks, it would take `18,446,744,073,709,551,616` times that because that is how many possible IPv6 `/64` networks there are.